# Azure Functions BlobTrigger tries to execute 5 times

Tags: azure-functions

There is a blob-triggered function. When triggered it fails due to an error in the code. Afterwards it triggers 4 additional times.

At the end this message is logged `Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'webjobs-blobtrigger-poison'.`

I do understand that blob triggers internally work with queues. In the host.json I have set `maxDequeueCount=1`. I was assuming this would also hold for the blobs, which is not the case.

In the blob section of the host.json I can only configure [maxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings).

How can I configure blob-triggerd function to only execute once per blob-trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Retry count per function right now is only supported for Event Hub triggers and Timer triggers via `[FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:00:10")]` attribute and only for running in-process.

Blob triggers should be bind to queue settings in host.json per docs , maybe this is a issue for they Github page!?

Answer (score 0):

From your answer it is not clear in which section of the host.json you have added **maxDequeueCount=1**.

Even though it is linked to the blob trigger, this setting has to be added in the **queues** section as shown below. This should work for the extension versions 2.x and higher.

{
"version": "2.0",
"extensions": {
"queues": {
"maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
"visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
"batchSize": 16,
**"maxDequeueCount": 1,**
"newBatchThreshold": 8,
"messageEncoding": "base64"
}
}
}

Comment: Hi, that property was set in the queues section. Unfortunately it didn't help. I have now abandoned using the blob trigger at all and instead use an event grid subscription for new blobs